# How to access functions in a C++ dll from python ,all I have is a package(a header file and a dll file)

Tags: python, c++, dll

Now I have a C++ (with classes) binary library (dll file) and a header file in hand, without the library's source code, then how can i access the functions in the dll from python ?

Answer (score 0):

### You might be interested in **Boost**

> The Boost Python Library is a framework for interfacing Python and
>   C++. It allows you to quickly and seamlessly expose C++ classes
>   functions and objects to Python, and vice-versa, using no special
>   tools -- just your C++ compiler. It is designed to wrap C++ interfaces
>   non-intrusively, so that you should not have to change the C++ code at
>   all in order to wrap it, making Boost.Python ideal for exposing
>   3rd-party libraries to Python. The library's use of advanced
>   metaprogramming techniques simplifies its syntax for users, so that
>   wrapping code takes on the look of a kind of declarative interface
>   definition language (IDL).
>   [Read more](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/)

### Or SWIG

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in
>   C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is
>   used with different types of target languages including common
>   scripting languages such as Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby. [Read more](http://www.swig.org).

**EDIT:** In response to jsbeuno's comment: AFAIK ctypes cannot natively interface with C++, only C.

Comment: ctypes would be more appropriate for this use case.